# How to annotate a field from a related model to queryset?

Tags: django, model, annotate

I have two models:

Lot:

```
class Lot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True)
    step = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2)
```

and Bid:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey('Lot', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='username')
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Every instance of Lot can have a few Bids, however any instance of Bid is only related to a particular Lot.

I have a working annotation for Lot that gives me the max_bid and next_bid values:

```
self.auc_set = Lot.objects.annotate(max_bid=Max('bid__value'), next_bid=(Max('bid__value') + F('step')))
```

And what i can't achieve is getting 3 annotated fields: max_bid, next_bid and last_bidder.

Something like:

```
self.auc_set = Lot.objects.annotate(max_bid=Max('bid__value'), next_bid=(Max('bid__value') + F('step')), last_bidder=F(bid_set).get('auction_id'= F('id'), 'value'=max_bid)['user_id'])
```

but working.

Update:
The problem would be solved if i knew how to pass the 'id' from Lot.objects.annotate to the Bid.objects.get part:

```
auc_set = Lot.objects.annotate(last_bidder=Bid.objects.get(auction_id__exact='need_to_put_something_here', value=Max('value').user_id)
```

Comment: Unless you specify a related_name on your Foreignkey, the related name (on `Lot`)  will be `bid_set`. So try `bid_set__value`.

Comment: Yes, i know that, but how can i annotate the user_id with the Max('value') from bid_set? I can get Max('bid_set__value') but value is not what i need, i need the user_id from that row where the value is max.

Comment: I don't know, but the code you posted had that error in it! (that's why I commented rather than answered).